# Minecraft will NOT load!

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, technical-issues

Upon starting my PC yesterday, I had a boot error and I had to remove everything and start fresh, I have installed Java Version 8 update 25 and the Java for Google Chrome but Modsauce (Modded Minecraft) will not start!

This is the error is gave me within the console of AT Launcher

```
[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] ATLauncher Version: 3.2.1.7

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Operating System: Windows 8.1

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] RAM Available: 16330MB

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Java Version: Launcher: 1.8.0_25, Minecraft: 1.8.0_25

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Java Path: C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] 64 Bit Java: true

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Launcher Directory: **USERSDIR**

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Using Theme: ATLauncher by RyanTheAllmighty

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Showing splash screen and loading everything

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Checking for updated files!

[18/10/2014 12:50:13 PM] Loading Language: English

[18/10/2014 12:50:18 PM] No updates found!
[18/10/2014 12:50:18 PM] [Background] Checking Minecraft Versions Started

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Checking account UUID's!

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Launcher finished loading everything

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Launcher opening

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Made By Bob*

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] *(Not Actually)

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Setting up Bottom Bar

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Finished Setting up Bottom Bar

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Setting up Tabs

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Finished Setting up Tabs

[18/10/2014 12:50:20 PM] Showing Launcher

[18/10/2014 12:50:23 PM] [Background] Checking Minecraft Versions Complete

[18/10/2014 12:50:28 PM] Checking Access Token!

[18/10/2014 12:50:30 PM] Access token checked and is valid!

[18/10/2014 12:50:30 PM] Refreshing Access Token!

[18/10/2014 12:50:30 PM] Launching Minecraft with the following arguments (user related     stuff has been removed): [C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25\bin\javaw, -XX:HeapDumpPath=MojangTricksIntelDriversForPerformance_javaw.exe_minecraft.exe.heapdump, -XX:-OmitStackTraceInFastThrow, -Xms256M, -Xmx4096M, -XX:MetaspaceSize=256M, -Duser.language=en, -Duser.country=US, -Dfml.log.level=INFO, -Djava.library.path=**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\natives, -cp, **USERSDIR**\ATLauncher.exe;anything;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\jarmods\forge-1.7.10-10.13.0.1208-universal.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\launchwrapper-1.9.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\asm-all-4.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\akka-actor_2.11-2.3.3.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\config-1.2.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-actors-migration_2.11-1.1.0.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-compiler-2.11.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-continuations-library_2.11-1.0.2.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-continuations-plugin_2.11.1-1.0.2.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-library-2.11.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-parser-combinators_2.11-1.0.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-reflect-2.11.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-swing_2.11-1.0.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\scala-xml_2.11-1.0.2.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\jopt-simple-4.5.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\lzma-0.0.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\realms-1.3.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\guava-16.0.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\commons-lang3-3.2.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\commons-compress-1.8.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\httpclient-4.3.3.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\commons-logging-1.1.3.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\httpcore-4.3.2.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\vecmath-1.3.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\trove4j-3.0.3.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\icu4j-core-mojang-51.2.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\codecjorbis-20101023.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\codecwav-20101023.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\libraryjavasound-20101123.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\librarylwjglopenal-20100824.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\soundsystem-20120107.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\netty-all-4.0.10.Final.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\commons-io-2.4.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\commons-codec-1.9.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\jinput-2.0.5.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\jutils-1.0.0.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\gson-2.2.4.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\authlib-1.5.16.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\log4j-api-2.0-beta9.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\log4j-core-2.0-beta9.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\lwjgl-2.9.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\lwjgl_util-2.9.1.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\twitch-5.16.jar;**USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce\bin\minecraft.jar, net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch, --username, REDACTED, --version, 1.7.10, --gameDir, **USERSDIR**\Instances\HermitcraftModsauce, --assetsDir, **USERSDIR**\Configs\Resources, --assetIndex, 1.7.10, --uuid, REDACTED, --accessToken, REDACTED, --userProperties, REDACTED, --userType, legacy, --width=854, --height=480, --tweakClass=cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker]

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Using primary tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLTweaker

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/INFO] [FML]: Forge Mod Loader version 7.10.25.1208 for Minecraft 1.7.10 loading

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/INFO] [FML]: Java is Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, version 1.8.0_25, running on Windows 8.1:amd64:6.3, installed at C:\Program Files\Java\jre1.8.0_25

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod mods.battlegear2.coremod.BattlegearLoadingPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod appeng.transformer.AppEngCore does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/INFO] [FML]: [AppEng] Core Init

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod aroma1997.core.coremod.CoreMod does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:32 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.core.launch.CodeChickenCorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] Warning: version of CodeChickenLib, 1.1.1.105 is newer than request 1.1.1.104

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] Warning: version of ForgeMultipart, 1.1.0.310 is newer than request 1.1.0.309

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] Warning: version of bspkrsCore, 6.14 is newer than request 6.12

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod cofh.asm.LoadingPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod fastcraft.LoadingPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod portablejim.fognerf.FogNerfCoremod does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.core.launch.DepLoader does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod invtweaks.forge.asm.FMLPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/INFO] [FML]: Loading tweaker com.mumfrey.liteloader.launch.LiteLoaderTweaker from liteloader-1.7.10.jar

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod mariculture.fishery.VanillaOverride does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod mekanism.common.asm.LoadingHook does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod micdoodle8.mods.miccore.MicdoodlePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod mcp.mobius.mobiuscore.asm.CoreDescription does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.nei.asm.NEICorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod openblocks.OpenBlocksCorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod openeye.CorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod openmods.OpenModsCorePlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.core.launch.DepLoader does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.core.launch.DepLoader does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod lumien.randomthings.Transformer.RTLoadingPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod schmoller.tubes.asm.TubesPlugin does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/WARN] [FML]: The coremod codechicken.core.launch.DepLoader does not have a MCVersion annotation, it may cause issues with this version of Minecraft

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name com.mumfrey.liteloader.launch.LiteLoaderTweaker

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Loading tweak class name cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLDeobfTweaker

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/INFO] [LaunchWrapper]: Calling tweak class cpw.mods.fml.common.launcher.FMLInjectionAndSortingTweaker

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] [main/ERROR] [LaunchWrapper]: Unable to launch

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM] java.util.ConcurrentModificationException

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM]    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM]    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.remove(Unknown Source) ~[?:1.8.0_25]

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM]    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.launch(Launch.java:117) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]

[18/10/2014 12:50:34 PM]    at net.minecraft.launchwrapper.Launch.main(Launch.java:28) [launchwrapper-1.9.jar:?]

[18/10/2014 12:50:35 PM] Checking for updated files!

[18/10/2014 12:50:35 PM] No updates found!

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] Connection refused: connect

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.net.TwoStacksPlainSocketImpl.socketConnect(Native Method)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.doConnect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connectToAddress(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.net.AbstractPlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.net.PlainSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.net.SocksSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.net.Socket.connect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.security.ssl.BaseSSLSocketImpl.connect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.NetworkClient.doConnect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.http.HttpClient.openServer(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.<init>(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsClient.New(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.getNewHttpClient(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect0(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.plainConnect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.https.AbstractDelegateHttpsURLConnection.connect(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream0(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] sun.net.www.protocol.https.HttpsURLConnectionImpl.getOutputStream(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] com.atlauncher.utils.Utils.sendAPICall(Utils.java:1154)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] com.atlauncher.data.Instance.addTimePlayed(Instance.java:1283)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] com.atlauncher.data.Instance$2$2.run(Instance.java:1211)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.util.concurrent.Executors$RunnableAdapter.call(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)

[18/10/2014 12:50:37 PM] Copied Log to clipboard
```

Comment: + fixed by changing and installing Java Version 7 Update 25

Comment: Then please either delete your question or post an answer and accept it. Abandoning questions without accepting an answer is considered very bad etiquette.

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's modded Minecraft tech support.

Answer (score 3):

Try downgrading to java 7, because (some) modloaders are not prepared for it.